# QGIS 3 Graphical Modeler pre calculated values using Advanced Field Calculator

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, expression

I have a new model that tries to create a new column using the Advanced Field Calculator and pre-calculated values. I just seem not able to get the syntax right on how to populate the attribute using the values stored in the Variable. Here is my example model.
[image]

The input data is depicted below
[image]

Basically what I am trying to do is fix up some bad geometries and then reclassify the layer based on attribute values.
I have tried the following formula:

```
 Case when attribute(get_feature(@layers,@InputFields,'WC')) then 1 ELSE NULL END
```

Or

```
Case When layer_property(@layer,@InputFields) = 'WC' then 1 else 2 end
```

All of the above formula do not give a clear answer. I have searched the browser for different answers but I haven't got any hints why I am getting an error when I execute the model.

Any hints or links to documentation.

Comment: I guess it'd be helpful if you shared a bit more about the vector layer you are using as input, maybe even example data and your model.

Comment: I have added more context and example showing the attribute table

Answer (score 1):

A correct syntax is this one here:

```
if (get_feature (@layer,  @InputFields , 'WC'), 1, 0)
```

Or, using `case`:

```
case 
when get_feature (@layer,  @InputFields , 'WC') then 1
else 0
end
```

However, you don't provide enough information to see if that is what you want.
The help in the expression editor is quite good and gives you ideas about the expressions available, the attributes expected and the syntax.